# Binding to ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,string>> results in Error XFC0045 Binding: Property "Item1" not found

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, tuples

I have an ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,string>>. I want to bind this string from the different tuples to my front-end.

When starting the emulator, I get an error that says the following: Error XFC0045 Binding: Property "Item1" not found.

**.xaml**

```
<ScrollView>
                <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultCollection}" SelectionMode="None">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackLayout>
                                <!-- Item 1 = UserAnswer -->
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource SubItem}" Text="{Binding Item1}"/>

                                <!-- Item 2 = CorrectAnswer -->
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource SubItem}" Text="{Binding Item2}"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </ScrollView>
```

**ViewModel**
UserAnswers and CorrectAnswers are both List.

```
ResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>();

for(int i = 0; i < UserAnswers.Count; i++)
{
    ResultCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(UserAnswers[i], CorrectAnswers[i]));
}
```

Can someone help me with the binding of this tuple in my .xaml?

Comment: BTW - IIRC - A `CollectionView` already scrolls. Unlikely to want to wrap it with a `ScrollView`. (This isn't the cause of your problem, but wanted to mention it.)

Comment: 1) emulator - android or ios? 2) That error is related to a `x:DataType=...` attribute somewhere. Please show the XAML containing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an `x:DataType` earlier in the page. Given that, for the binding to work inside the CollectionView, you'll need to also have an `x:DataType` statement on the ItemTemplate or DataTemplate, specifying its type.

But you can't, if the bound data involves a Generic Type (`...<...>`).

This is a limitation of `x:DataType` declaration in XAML.

See [Enhancement Allow generics in x:DataType](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7161).

---

Fix #1:

- REMOVE ALL `x:DataType` statements in the XAML file.

PRO: XF will figure out what to do at run-time. Will probably work without further changes in your code.

CON: Possible performance issues, if many items in collection.

---

Fix #2:

Define a custom class for your items, that has the properties. Use that class name in `x:DataType` on the ItemTemplate's DataTemplate.

MyTuple.cs:

```
public class MyTuple : Tuple<string, string>
{
    public MyTuple(string item1, string item2) : base(item1, item2)
    {
    }
}
```

MyContentPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage ...
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceHere"   <-- replace YourNamespaceHere
     ...>

...
    <CollectionView ...
        ...
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyTuple">
        ...
```

.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyTuple> ResultCollection { get; set; }

private void Init()
{
    ResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyTuple> {
        new MyTuple("a", "abcabc")
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple)

> C# tuples, which are backed by System.ValueTuple types, are different
> from tuples that are represented by System.Tuple types. The main
> differences are as follows:
>
> - ValueTuple types are value types. Tuple types are reference types.
> - ValueTuple types are mutable. Tuple types are immutable.
> - Data members of ValueTuple types are fields. Data members of Tuple types are properties.

you can only bind to **public properties**, so binding will only work with `System.Tuple`

Answer (score 0):

1.Set your `ResultCollection` property to public.

2.Set the `BindingContext` in your Background code.

3.Since you set `x:name`. You can also use similar in your Background code: `ItemsListView.ItemsSource = ResultCollection;`

I wrote a small example for your reference.

Here is the background code(The xaml code is consistent with the one you provided):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>> ResultCollection { get; set; }//Set public
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ResultCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
        }
        BindingContext = this;// Set BindingContext
    }
}
```